# For finding the server name I opened SQL Server Configuration Manager but I am getting an error - what should I do?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I get this error:

> Cannot connect to WMI provider. You do not have permission or the
>   server is unreachable. Note that you can only manage SQL Server 2005
>   and later servers with SQL Server Configuration Manager. Invalid
>   namespace [0x8004100e]

To find the server name, I opened SQL Server Configuration Manager, but I get this error mentioned above. What should I do?

I am a beginner at SQL Server - please help me with this.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Are other people able to connect to this server?

Comment: Have you worked through: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/956013/error-message-when-you-open-sql-server-configuration-manager-in-sql-se

Comment: yes i have gone through this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/956013/error-message-when-you-open-sql-server-configuration-manager-in-sql-se        but still can't solve my problem